# include old library in C++ namespace

Tags: c++, header, namespaces

I'm trying to use two old (and different) usb libraries in a bigger project by encapsulating them into their own namespace like so:

```
namespace usbA {
#include "/msp430/usb.h"
}
namespace usbB {
#include "/cypress/usb.h"
}
```

This leads to linker errors obviously because the names in the actual libraries are not decorated with the namespaces as are the function calls.
Can this be solved without editing the libraries code?
According to some other posters answers this cannot be done. This begs the question of what are namespaces good for then? If I have to go in and modify library source code I can as well prefix each function with "usbA_" instead of using namespace at all. It's equally inflexible.

Comment: You can use a tool like `objcopy` with `--redefine-sym` to rename the routines in a `.so`. I'm not familiar enough with windows symbol remapping to be able to offer an option in that area.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This leads to linker errors obviously because the names in the actual libraries are not decorated with the namespaces as are the function calls. Can this be solved without editing the libraries code?

I'm sure there will be ghastly ways to hack this, but I would really just … not. In my opinion it's bound to end in tears.

If you *really* need both libraries, and their names really conflict, I think on balance you're probably best off forking them and giving them namespaces yourself.

> This begs the question of what are namespaces good for then?

They're good for nothing *if you don't use them* (and C code obviously doesn't use them). If these libraries were C++ projects with namespaces, then you wouldn't have this problem, which is good for quite a lot.

> It's equally inflexible

Well, this is why C++ introduced namespaces. Sadly you can't force everyone to write C++.

Comment: _"Sadly you can't force everyone to write C++."_ Can't believe I said that

Comment: If these libraries were C++ projects with namespaces, then you wouldn't have this problem. How is that? If they for example are both C++ USB libraries and both of them use the namespace "USB" you were in the same mess. I can't go and modify one libraries namespace to "usbA" for example, can I? I would have to go in and modify the actual source of the library to change the namespace. Again if I do that, I can as well just use old school prefixes instead of namespaces and edit the library that way. What do namespaces give me? I can't encapsulate a library the way I want it with it.

Comment: @dsula: Well, granted, if two libraries pick the _same_ namespace name then you're back to square one, but sensible developers don't use such trivial names. If you have an alternative suggestion that somehow solves name conflicts universally for all cases both known and unknown, feel free to propose it to the standard committee, but otherwise to be honest it kind of seems like you're just complaining. What exactly _is_ "the way [you] want"?

Comment: No, I'm not complaining :-). I'm wondering. First time I use this namespace stuff and probably I'm ignorant but for me it doesn't do what I would consider useful functionality. I can get the same functionality by adding a prefix to each library function and class name. But then again, I'm not really a power C++ user. So maybe there are different advantages, which I don't see. Meanwhile I guess you answered my question: It's not possible to encapsulate a legacy library in a namespace without modifying said librarie's source code. Too bad.

Comment: @dsula: _"I can get the same functionality by adding a prefix to each library function and class name"_ Ish, but that's significantly more unwieldy, and doesn't give you any of the _scoping_ and _name lookup_ benefits.